# limit formalisms

Tags: real-analysis, big-list, probability-limit-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function and $a\in \mathbb R$ a point. The Cauchy definition of the limit $\lim _{x\to a}f(x)=L$ is well-known. For pedagogical reasons I'm interesting in a comprehensive list of other, equivalent, formalisms. For instance, the Heine concept of limit: if $x_n$ converges to $a$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$, is an equivalent formalism to the Cauchy definition, one that relies on the notion of limit of a sequence.

At least two other formalisms I can think of are 1) using the hyperreals (i.e., $f(x)$ is infinitesimally close to $L$ whenever $x$ is infinitesimally close to $a$) and 2) using filters (i.e., the filter generated by the direct image of a filter converging to $a$, converges to $L$) both relying on some set-theoretic constructions.

Any other formalism that can be added to the four above will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You left out [Moore–Smith convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29). But I don't know that filters and nets are all that interesting in the context of the real numbers anyhow. They are much more powerful and general tools, but provide nothing new in elementary analysis.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I'm looking for formalisms of the limit notion in the context of real functions, just for simplicity. I left out Moore-Smith convergence since it is an unnecessary generalization in the context of metric spaces; i.e., sequences suffice. Filters are different though. They are very powerful but also in the context of the reals, they are very useful. One may say that they provide a more elegant formalization than the Cauchy one.